# What is the progress to create a custom audio player like on Spotify?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I was looking around to create a custom audio player like these:

---

[Spotify audio player](https://play.spotify.com/)

[image: Spotify Audio Player]

[Bamboom audio player](http://baboom.com/kimdotcom/)

[image: Bamboom audio player]

---

What is the progress to create those player? Is it HTML5 `<audio>` or a custom JS code? Any pointer, help, or code would be very helpful. I'm a designer and I deal with CSS very well, I have a developer that deal with JS (NodeJS/AngularJS) and we're interested if creating those audio player is within our capability.

Answer (score 0):

As of a year ago to render the audio go with web audio API - its [supported](http://caniuse.com/audio-api) on all modern browsers - however it leaves as an exercise to the readers the work of supplying to it a stream of audio data ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best skin designer out there is the [wimpy skin machine](http://www.wimpyplayer.com/skinmachine/). You can use the tool and export CSS and HTML for other player engines as well.

Here are some examples of skins created with the tool:
http://www.wimpyplayer.com/skins/